# Mongoid 3.1.4 undefined method 'has_key?' when calling 'Document.create'

Tags: ruby, mongoid, mongodb-ruby

I'm having a problem trying to use Mongoid (v 3.1.4) to persist a (really simple) entity to MongoDB (v 2.4.4). I'm using MRI and Ruby 2.0.0-p195 on OS X.

Here's my class (Person.rb):

```
require 'mongoid'

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps # currently can be ommitted

  field :name, type: String

  def initialize
    # is empty
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(value)
    @name = value
  end

end

Mongoid.load!('config/mongoid.yml', :development)

user = Person.new
user.name = "John Doe"
user.create
```

That last sentence greets me with a

[...]mongoid/attributes.rb:320:in 'method_missing': undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Here's my 'mongoid.yml':

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: rbtest
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
test:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: test
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        consistency: :strong
        max_retries: 1
        retry_interval: 0
```

Connection to the DB instance seems ok as the DB is created ('rbtest') however, Collections and Documents fail. I've already tried with 'create!' and 'safely.save!' to no avail.

I tried implementing the has_key? method, for which I couldn't find any documentation, so I'm at a bit of a loss here.

As always, any help is much appreciated.

Regards,

---

#### UPDATE -- SOLUTION:

@Frederik Cheung's answer was spot on. Here's the working code (updated with @mu-is-too-short's suggestion)

```
require 'mongoid'

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
end

Mongoid.load!('config/mongoid.yml', :development)

person = Person.new(:name => 'John Doe')
person.save!
```

Comment: You're right, at least according to the official docs :D
Updated my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your `initialize` method: you are overriding the one provided by mongoid, so some of mongoid's internals aren't being setup.

You need to either remove your initialize method or call the mongoid's implementation via `super`